# When PlayerRemoving event is fired, for loop does not work properly

Tags: lua, savegame, roblox

while I was implementing the Backback save feature in my Roblox Game (using `game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect()`, I found that when I used a loop of any form (`for`, `while`,etc.), it would not run correctly. Here is a test program which I wrote to observe this issue:

```
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local testList = {"Hello", ",", "world"}
    for i=1,3,1
    do
        print(testList[i])
    end
end)
```

However, when this code is ran, all I see in the output window is:

```
Hello
```

And nothing else.
This issue is causing a lot of issues with the rest of the code, can somebody please help? It would be very useful!

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code as I didn't see anything wrong with it and it works fine. Be sure to check if there are any yields, breaks, anything that could stop PlayerRemoving event from firing / executing the whole code.

Comment: I am afraid the code I posted at the top is *it*, and yet I only get one Hello.

Comment: As I said works fine for me. Your studio may have an issue maybe your studio is bugged? try re installing or testing in a  real game , if it works there it means your studio is bugged and has to be re installed.